# Run Function When Loggin To Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I thought this would be simple thing to figure out but I have not been able find any examples.

I just want to run a function whenever a user logs in to the Django Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in` signal.  If you only want to call the function for admin logins check the request against your admin urlconf.